# server.local resolving to wrong NIC / IP from mDNS

Tags: networking, mdns

I run a headless 22.04 server with 2 NIC
both are configured and plugged into the LAN
one is configured as 192.168.0.1, router and other machines on this subnet
the other is set as 192.168.2.1 for future home automation

If I ping machines with `.local` all other machines work.

If I ping server `.local` it tries to ping the .2.1 and not the 0.1
Using Avahi discover the server advertises itself only as 192.168.2.1

I know I could set up routing but would prefer to keep them segmented/airgapped
I know I could unplug the currently little used subnet
I run BIND and can ping using server. but want to solve this little issue properly and learn a little more re-networking

What do I need to change in the config to make it announce the correct (main) subnet?